# Is there a way to change the "external" border of a QPushButton?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to change the **look** of the `QPushButton` of my application to be similar to the **PyCharm** ones.
I almost made it but I would like to change the "external" border of the button on **focus**.

To better explain myself, two screenshots are posted below: the first shows a PyCharm dialog with the focus on the OK button and the second shows part of a dialog of my application with the focus on the OK button as well.

[image]

[image]

The buttons are similar but in the first picture the border "grows" outwards while in the second the border "grows" inwards.

Is there a way to change this "property" through the **stylesheet**?

My stylesheet below:

```
QPushButton{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 8pt;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgb(46, 103, 156); 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(77, 138, 201);
    color: white;
    font: bold;
    width: 64px;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(33, 77, 115);
}
QPushButton:focus {
    outline-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgb(151, 195, 243);
}
QPushButton:pressed{
    background-color: rgb(52, 113, 173);
}
QPushButton:disabled {
    color: grey;
    border-color: grey;
    background-color: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a default margin (which sets the margins between the effective widget rectangle and its *drawn* contents), and set it to 0 for the `focus` selector:

```
QPushButton {
    ...
    margin: 1px;
}
QPushButton:focus {
    ...
    margin: 0px;
}
```